# alignment of objects in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I added some buttons to BoxSizer.
This I what I wanted:
[image]

This is what I go:
[image]

This is the code for the 2nd Box:

```
    self.approveItem = wx.Button(self.panel_1, -1, "Approve Item")
    self.changeQty = wx.Button(self.panel_1, -1, "Change Qty")
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_2.Add(self.approveItem, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 0)
    sizer_2.Add(self.changeQty, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT| wx.RIGHT, 0)
    self.sizer_item_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "")
    sizer_item = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_item_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_item.SetMinSize((600,-1))
    sizer_item.Add(sizer_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
```

how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to achieve what you want, including using a flexgridsizer, a gridsizer and just normal horizontal and vertical boxsizers, here is a gridsizer example.
I have made it 5 columns wide, so that you can insert extra buttons on the left hand side if you so wish.
See: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GridSizer.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, wx.DefaultPosition)
        Buttons = []
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,-1, "Approve Location"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,-1, "Approve Item"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,-1, "Change Qty"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,-1, "Approve"))
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,3)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[0], (0, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[1], (1, 4), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[2], (1, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[3], (2, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Centre()
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Gridbagsizer")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below would give the result you want.

[image]

Note however, that aligning is done by use of setting the proportion and by adding a spacer, which pushes the buttons to the right. I find this much more understandable/readable than fiddling around with the alignment flags.

```
    # Defining panel
    self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self,-1)

    # create dummy button quick
    quickbtn = lambda label: wx.Button(self.panel_1, -1, label)

    stat1 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel_1, -1)
    stsz1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(stat1, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    stsz1.Add((0,0), 1) # dummy spacer with proportion 1 filling the space on the left
    stsz1.Add(quickbtn('btn1'), 0, wx.EXPAND)

    stat2 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel_1, -1)
    stsz2 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(stat2, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    stsz2.Add((0,0), 1)
    stsz2.Add(quickbtn('btn2_A'), 0, wx.EXPAND)
    stsz2.Add(quickbtn('btn2_B'), 0, wx.EXPAND)

    szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    szmain.Add(stsz1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)
    szmain.Add(stsz2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)

    self.panel_1.SetSizer(szmain)
```

Comment: That doesn' work... I mean it does work but only if the sizer is on the whole line.. till the end of the screen.. then there is no more right for it to expand.... you don't take under considration the SetMinSize

Comment: Your example above does not work (does not lead to the screenshot with the "Change Qty" button sticking out on the right): I strongly suggest you create a minimum working example, otherwise it is not even clear what you are even talking about.